# How to assign array A values to array B in JS/appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am developing some Stock tools with AppScript and now I dont know why I cannot assign the array A values to array B. Could someone help me ?

I want to copy the values_array [l][0] -> dataArray [l][0]

Could you please give me the solution please?

```js
//Filled up the array for MACD 
// var dataArray = [["Stock","Date","Close Price","EMA12","EMA26","DIF","Signal"]];
var dataArray = [];
var accumulationEMA12 = 0;

for (var l = 0; l < values_array.length - 1; l++) // Get the previous day EMA12
{
  var temp = values_array[l][5];

  //  var accumulationEMA12 ＝ accumulationEMA12 + values_array[l][5];

  var accumulationEMA12 = accumulationEMA12 + temp;

  dataArray[l][0] = values_array[l][0]; // Fill Up the Stock No. <-Here
  dataArray[l][1] = values_array[l][1]; // Fill UP the Date <-Here


  if (l < 11) //if the dataset is < 12 rows or < 26 rows, calculate the average instead of EMA
  {

  }
}
```

```js
 //Filled up the array for MACD 
   // var dataArray = [["Stock","Date","Close Price","EMA12","EMA26","DIF","Signal"]];
    var dataArray = [];
    var accumulationEMA12 = 0;
    
    for(var l = 0; l< values_array.length-1; l++) // Get the previous day EMA12
    {  
      var temp = values_array[l][5];
   
    //  var accumulationEMA12 ＝ accumulationEMA12 + values_array[l][5];
      
      var accumulationEMA12 = accumulationEMA12 + temp;

      dataArray[l][0] = values_array[l][0]; // Fill Up the Stock No.
      dataArray[l][1] = values_array[l][1]; // Fill UP the Date
      
          
      
      if(l < 11) //if the dataset is < 12 rows or < 26 rows, calculate the average instead of EMA
      {
       
      }
    }
```

Values_array here [image]

Comment: What is `values_array`?

Comment: values_array's values:
values_array[][0] - Stock No. (Number)
values_array[][1] - Date.  (String)
values_array[][2] - Open Price (Number)
values_array[][3] - Lowest Price (Number)
values_array[][4] - Highest Price (Number)
values_array[][5] - Close Price (Number)
values_array[][6] - Vol. (Number)

Comment: where is your value array ?

Comment: I have place an image for values_array upon. Please help .

Comment: Please don't provide that as image, but in JavaScript syntax, so we can run the code with that data.

Comment: Also, please explain what you mean with "I cannot assign...". Do you get an error? Do you get a result that you did not expect? Please provide details.

Comment: Since I call importHTML and put all those raw data into the values_array, so I couldn't provide the code :(

and actually the meaning of cannot assign is that after execute the line of code, I cannot see any values assign but no error occur... I try to keep run the line of code but I see the debugger is keep concat. like that -> dataArray[0] , dataArray[0][0], datArray[0][0][0].........hope you know my meaning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting error at the line

```
dataArray[l][0] = values_array[l][0];
```

Because, no where I see you have initiated `dataArray[l]`. In your code, `dataArray[l]` is `undefined`, so when you try to do something like `dataArray[l][1]`, you are essentially doing `undefined[1]` which will throw such type error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

So what you need to do is, make sure `dataArray[l]` is an array itself. Something like this

```
var dataArray = [];
for (var l = 0; l < values_array.length; l++) {
  // make sure dataArray[l] exists
  dataArray[l] = [];

  // do your operations
  dataArray[l][0] = values_array[l][0];
  dataArray[l][1] = values_array[l][1];

  // other code.
}
```

Although, I would suggest using modern JS language features, like

```
const dataArray = [];
values_array.forEach((val, index)=> {
  // notice that we are assigning a new array to dataArray[index] 
  dataArray[index] = [
    val[0],
    val[1],
  ];

  // do other operations like
  if (index < 11) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.